# Locating element with python selenium using href in xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have an issue locating element in `Python` `Selenium` using `href` within `XPath`. I have checked that my `XPath` is correct using `Chrome` console and I am happy with the result it returns.

I used the following to validate `XPath` on `Chrome` Console:

```
$x("//li[@id='result_0']//a[@href='https://www.amazon.co.uk/HuntGold-Plastic-Outdoor-Carrier-Container/dp/B00R7DCPWO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1476540708&sr=8-1&keywords=banana+holder#customerReviews']")
```

Then I used the same `XPath` in my `Python` `Selenium` code:

```
path = "//li[@id='result_0]//a[@href='https://www.amazon.co.uk/HuntGold-Plastic-Outdoor-Carrier-Container/dp/B00R7DCPWO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1476540708&sr=8-1&keywords=banana+holder#customerReviews']"
reviews = driver.find_element_by_xpath(path).text
```

and I got the following error message:

```
reviews = driver.find_element_by_xpath(reviews_path).text
File "/Users/Paulius/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 293, in find_element_by_xpath
return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
File "/Users/Paulius/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
'value': value})['value']
File "/Users/Paulius/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Users/Paulius/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
(Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.143)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243 (0bfa1d3575fc1044244f21ddb82bf870944ef961),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.0 x86_64)
```

Does anyone know how to get `href` `XPath` in `Python` `Selenium` working?

Comment: Show us `HTML` for element you try to handle

Comment: It's possible that some portion of that URL changes for different types of pageloads.  In general, matching a string that large is a bad idea.  If you must match by href, consider doing something like `//li[@id='result_0]//a[contains(@href, 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/HuntGold-Plastic-Outdoor-Carrier-Container/']`

Comment: your xpath is not returning any element from the page.....can you explain for which element you want to get the text.